# protoype js 1.0.6 is conflicting with chart js

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, prototype, conflict

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.0.3/prototype.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <canvas id="myChart" width="100" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
        window.onload = () => {
            let myElm = document.createElement("script");   // Create a new element

            myElm.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.3/prototype.min.js';
            myElm.setAttribute ('defer' ,true); // Change the text of the element
            myElm.setAttribute ('type'  ,'module'); // Change the text of the elementù
            //document.querySelector('head').prepend(myElm);    // Add the object to the DOM
        }
        let jq =  jQuery.noConflict()
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.3/prototype.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" defer >
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log(Prototype.Version);
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So if you will remove comment from
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.0.3/prototype.min.js
script tag it will stop working and show error in console

x-axios 0.undefined

1. I tried to add me prototype on project it is inside code will it is still conflicting even I also tried noConflict method in jquery

Comment: I need prototype 1.6.0 in my project so i cannot remove that

Answer (score 0):

Issue is not in chart.js. If you remove everyhting except for prototyp it still throws the same error that this.each is not defined. So it seems to be a bug in that version of prototype. So to solve it you just need to update to a newer version.

Comment: yes but that project setup i have I can't use the newer one. another thing I also need is prototype js 1.0.6.3 so I can not remove that 

I just need a way to use or configure the chart js with the older version of the prototype. nothing else I can only work without any support of any js or you can dependency.